# ProtocolViolation Exception on request stream.write() in windows mobile 6.5

Tags: windows-mobile-6.5

In my windows mobile application i am trying to write a video file with boundaries.
If i place the boundaries i am receiving protocol exception but if i am not using any boundary it works fine.

Below is my code

```
Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        byte[] boundaryData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(twoHyphens+boundary+lineEnd);
        byte[] boundaryData1 = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd );

        String headertemp = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\""+ GetCamera.videoFilePath+ "\""+ lineEnd;
        byte[] headerData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(headertemp);
        byte[] lineend = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(lineEnd);

        requestStream.Write(boundaryData, 0, boundaryData.Length);
        requestStream.Write(headerData, 0, headerData.Length);
        requestStream.Write(lineend, 0, lineend.Length);
        using (Stream video = File.OpenRead(GetCamera.videoFilePath))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            while ((bytesRead = video.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        }
        requestStream.Write(lineend, 0, lineend.Length);
        requestStream.Write(boundaryData1, 0, boundaryData.Length);
        requestStream.Close();
        requestStream.Dispose();
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Please forward your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I donot know the reason but when i increased the value for  content length property,it worked fine.